# Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2119-10-19T18:07:58Z. Error Code: 0x80041316

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server

our Windows Server 2012 Essentials is getting evenvwr poluted with the error message bellow and attached every 30 seconds. I've done a lot of research but nothing worked so far, this is what I tried:

- Check the NETWORK SERVICE permissions on C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows (it has FULL CONTROL)
- checked services and its dependencies and ensure they are running and have startup mode = automatic
- checked windows license with slmgr /ato
- started and stopped sppsvc service with net stop sppsvc/ net start sppsvc

This is our domain controler so I can't reinstall Windows - Any help please?

Log Name:      Application

Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP

Date:          11/12/2019 1:07:58 PM

Event ID:      16385

Task Category: None

Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Computer:      DC20001811

Description:

Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2119-10-
19T18:07:58Z. Error Code: 0x80041316.

Event Xml:

Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event":

System:

```
 Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" Guid="{E23B33B0-C8C9-472C-A5F9-F2BDFEA0F156}" EventSourceName="Software Protection Platform Service" : 

 EventID Qualifiers="49152": 16385 EventID: 

 Version: 0 Version: 

 Level: 2 Level: 

 Task: 0 Task: 

 Opcode: 0 Opcode: 

 Keywords: 0x80000000000000 Keywords: 

 TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-11-12T18:07:58.000000000Z" : 

 EventRecordID: 4441021 EventRecordID: 

 Correlation : 

 Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" : 

 Channel: Application Channel: 

 Computer: Andromeda.snapd.local Computer: 

 Security :
```

System:

EventData:

```
 Data: 0x80041316 Data: 

 Data: 2119-10-19T18:07:58Z Data:
```

EventData:

Event:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPrTq.png)

[NETWORK SERVICE account has Read permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Fuw.png)

[Service is set to use the NETWORK SERVICE account 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31FZz.png)

[Service is set to use the NETWORK SERVICE account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxTKx.png)

[Task Scheduler service is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7xie.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, the problem is that the eventvwr is getting this error every 30 seconds and, after researching a lot and trying a couple of different things, I couldn't get this resolved. What I need is a help to identify the root cause of this error and resolve it.

Comment: Provide the relevant information (screenshot) for each potential resolution described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3033200/failed-to-schedule-software-protection-service-for-restart-error-in-wi).  While you have specified you verified the permissions on a folder, it's not clear, if you verified the permissions on the folder specified in the support article for this problem.  This error being generated, is specifically connected to a permission problem, on a folder surrounding the task scheduler.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, thanks a million for the help, I couldn't find how to attach the images here in the comment session, so I added to the original question. I hope this helps, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This series of steps worked for me.  It is an abbreviated version of [this solution](https://shocksolution.com/2016/10/08/failed-to-schedule-software-protection-service-for-re-start-error-code-0x80041316/).

1. Back up all files in the directory `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\SoftwareProtectionPlatform` just in case
2. Add an XML extension to the files in the `SoftwareProtectionPlatform` folder
3. Navigate to to Computer Management->System Tools->Task Scheduler->Task Scheduler Library->Microsoft->Windows->SoftwareProtectionPlatform
4. Right-click on each task and select Delete
5. Right-click on SoftwareProtectionPlatform, Import Task, and import each of the files that you renamed.  Don't worry if they don't appear in the Task List.
6. Navigate to Computer Management->Services and Applications->Services and restart the Software Protection service
7. Check the Event Viewer to verify that the errors have stopped
8. Delete the XML files in the `SoftwareProtectionPlatform` folder

Comment: Deleting, re-importing task and restarting service appeared to fix this for me.